# I have written the code below in VBA (Excel), but it gives me the wrong result?

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have written this code in VBA:

```
Sub getdata()

    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim rcell As Range

    Sheets("Material Data").Select

    With Sheets("Material Data")
        y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each rcell In Range("C10:C62")
        If rcell > 1 Then rcell.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        y = y + 1
    Next rcell

End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that in the C10:C62 range, there are only 6 values greater than 1 (3 of them is 65 and the other 3 is 60). But this somehow pastes 53 values in sheet1 and 24 of them is 65 and rest 60. I have no idea where is it getting the 53 values from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to `paste` your values when they are above 1, but your `if-then` statement only includes the `Copy` operation, but your `paste` operation is executed for each cell. Try changing your code as follows:

```
If rcell > 1 Then 
    rcell.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    y = y + 1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! you are a genius...to think it was that simple. I spent an hour thinking what is wrong here

Comment: You are welcome :) If this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.